# PySpark calculate averages when value changes

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a df measuring fuel level % and refueling status. When refueling happens value is 1, otherwise 0.
Here is a sample df

```
+-----------------------+---------+---------+
|timestamp              |level %  |refueling|
+-----------------------+---------+---------+
|2020-08-01 00:09:41    |53.0     |1        |
|2020-08-01 00:14:41    |52.0     |0        |
|2020-08-01 02:19:41    |51.0     |0        |
|2020-08-01 04:24:41    |50.0     |0        |
|2020-08-01 06:29:41    |49.0     |0        |
|2020-08-01 08:44:41    |83.0     |1        |
|2020-08-01 10:49:41    |82.0     |0        |
|2020-08-01 12:54:41    |81.0     |0        |
|2020-08-01 14:59:41    |80.0     |0        |
|2020-08-01 16:04:41    |79.0     |0        |
|2020-08-01 18:09:41    |92.0     |1        |
|2020-08-01 20:14:41    |91.0     |0        |
|2020-08-01 22:19:41    |90.0     |0        |
|2020-08-02 00:24:41    |89.0     |0        |
+-----------------------+---------+---------+
```

I want to calculate the averages of `level %` values until the refueling happens (`refueling` column value is 1), write the calculated average as new column, and repeat the same process by considering the next  Following is the output I want to reach

```
+-----------------------+---------+---------+---------+
|timestamp              |level %  |refueling|average  |
+-----------------------+---------+---------+---------+
|2020-08-01 00:09:41    |53.0     |1        |45.9     |--> from previous calculations
|2020-08-01 00:14:41    |52.0     |0        |null     |
|2020-08-01 02:19:41    |51.0     |0        |null     |
|2020-08-01 04:24:41    |50.0     |0        |null     |
|2020-08-01 06:29:41    |49.0     |0        |null     |
|2020-08-01 08:44:41    |83.0     |1        |51.0     |--> (53+52+51+50+49)/5
|2020-08-01 10:49:41    |82.0     |0        |null     |
|2020-08-01 12:54:41    |81.0     |0        |null     |
|2020-08-01 14:59:41    |80.0     |0        |null     |
|2020-08-01 16:04:41    |79.0     |0        |null     |
|2020-08-01 18:09:41    |92.0     |1        |81.0     |--> (83+82+81+80+79)/5
|2020-08-01 20:14:41    |91.0     |0        |null     |
|2020-08-01 22:19:41    |90.0     |0        |null     |
|2020-08-02 00:24:41    |89.0     |0        |null     |
+-----------------------+---------+---------+---------+
```

I tried `window` function with rolling average,

```
w = Window.partitionBy(F.col("refueling")).orderBy(F.col("timestamp").asc())
df_diesel_rolling_ave = measurement_df_diesel.withColumn('average', F.avg("value_dbl").over(w))
```

but it generated continuous averages for every row, instead of starting a new average calculation after every `refueling 1`. What would be the approach for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my try, you can change the initial value from 0 to what you want.

```
from pyspark.sql import Window

w1 = Window.orderBy('timestamp')
w2 = Window.partitionBy('group')

r = df.withColumn('group', sum('refueling').over(w1)) \
  .withColumn('avg', when(expr('refueling == 1'), lag(avg('level %').over(w2), 1, 0).over(w1)))

r.show()

+-------------------+-------+---------+-----+----+
|          timestamp|level %|refueling|group| avg|
+-------------------+-------+---------+-----+----+
|2020-08-01 00:09:41|   53.0|        1|    1| 0.0|
|2020-08-01 00:14:41|   52.0|        0|    1|null|
|2020-08-01 02:19:41|   51.0|        0|    1|null|
|2020-08-01 04:24:41|   50.0|        0|    1|null|
|2020-08-01 06:29:41|   49.0|        0|    1|null|
|2020-08-01 08:44:41|   83.0|        1|    2|51.0|
|2020-08-01 10:49:41|   82.0|        0|    2|null|
|2020-08-01 12:54:41|   81.0|        0|    2|null|
|2020-08-01 14:59:41|   80.0|        0|    2|null|
|2020-08-01 16:04:41|   79.0|        0|    2|null|
|2020-08-01 18:09:41|   92.0|        1|    3|81.0|
|2020-08-01 20:14:41|   91.0|        0|    3|null|
|2020-08-01 22:19:41|   90.0|        0|    3|null|
|2020-08-02 00:24:41|   89.0|        0|    3|null|
+-------------------+-------+---------+-----+----+
```

Comment: This `w1 = Window.orderBy('timestamp')` is very dangerous as all the data happens to be moved to a single partition and may leads to an OOME.